# Android: error downloading text file from the web

Tags: android

I have an app with 4 tabs, one being to update an input text file from the web and write it to the sd card. My code executes because of try catch blocks, but the trace shows connection errors. The file gets written to the sd card, but it is 0 bytes. So the file writing is good, but I think there's hhtp connection problems. I'm using Windows 7 64 bit with the latest sdk.

Here's my code:

```
    public void downloadFile (String urlfile) throws IllegalStateException, IOException
    {

    InputStream instream = null;
    String result = null;


    try {
     //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
     //this is the file to be downloaded

             URL url = new URL(urlfile);


     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

     // Prepare a request object
      HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urlfile); 

     // Execute the request
      HttpResponse response;

      File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myfile.txt");    

      FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

              OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    fileOutput);

      try {
           response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

           // Examine the response status
           Log.i("Praeda",response.getStatusLine().toString());

           // Get hold of the response entity
               HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

           // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
           // to worry about connection release

           if (entity != null) {

                // A Simple JSON Response Read
                instream = entity.getContent();
                result= convertStreamToString(instream);

                 // now you have the string representation of the HTML request


            }

            myOutWriter.write(result);
            instream.close();
            myOutWriter.close();
                fileOutput.close();

            //catch some possible errors...


            } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }


    //catch some possible errors...

    } catch (Exception e)  {
         e.printStackTrace();
    } finally  {
    }

}


    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
    {
    /*
     * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
     * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
     * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
     * and returned as String.
    */

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            } 
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        return sb.toString();

    }
```

Here's the logcat output:

```
    W/ActivityManager(278): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40f82428


    W/System.err(720): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    W/System.err(720): at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
    W/System.err(720): at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
    W/System.err(720): at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
    W/System.err(720): at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
    W/System.err(720): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
    W/System.err(720): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    W/System.err(720): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    W/System.err(720): at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
    W/System.err(720): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
    W/System.err(720): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    W/System.err(720): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
    W/System.err(720): at com.gmail.tenglish7.lae.MainActivity$UpdateFragment.downloadFile(MainActivity.java:506)
    W/System.err(720): at com.gmail.tenglish7.lae.MainActivity$UpdateFragment.myClick(MainActivity.java:466)
    W/System.err(720): at com.gmail.tenglish7.lae.MainActivity$UpdateFragment$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:448)
    W/System.err(720): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
    W/System.err(720): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
    W/System.err(720): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    W/System.err(720): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    W/System.err(720): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    W/System.err(720): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    W/System.err(720): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    W/System.err(720): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    W/System.err(720): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    W/System.err(720): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    W/System.err(720): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's my Manifest.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.gmail.tenglish7.lae"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="14"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />



        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.gmail.tenglish7.lae.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
         </application>

    </manifest>
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One more person is going to learn how to use AsyncTask... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Answer (score 1):

Android throws an exception when you try to do network related operations on the main thread.
Call your `downloadFile` method from an `AsyncTask`. It will solve the problem.

```
class FileDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        downloadFile(params[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

You could then download the file using the below code.

```
new FileDownloadTask().execute(url);
```

Comment: How do you do that? I have no experience with that. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Guide to create your AsyncTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I got it already done. Thanks. My app now works and is almost ready for deployment.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to do so. Sorry.